# CSS Transition happening instantaneously

Tags: javascript, css, css-transitions

I'm working on a JavaScript tool on the Mod.it website, and for some reason, whenever I try to make a CSS Transition (by applying a new CSS style to a div with transition properties) it happens as soon as the program is launched (I suspect at compile time). I would like it to happen at runtime instead but the only way I've managed to do that is by setting a Timeout of less than a millisecond and that's the only thing that works.

If you take a look at the mod below, you'll notice that commenting out the timeout will remove the animation. If some of the code doesn't make sense, feel free to look at the modit-ui Library (found in the code tab).

https://mod.it/KDWeFcYD

If anyone can help me make my CSS transitions happen without having to set a timeout, which is much cleaner, I will be very grateful.

Comment: Please read [Something on my web site doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125997/something-on-my-web-site-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it)

Comment: Javascript "runtime" is when you load the page, so your question doesn't make much sense; there's no separate "compile time" for browser applications. If you want something to happen in response to the user doing something, put it in an event handler.

Comment: @Quentin - It's not a website I'm working on, it's just an app inside of the Mod.it compiler. I pasted the link so others could understand where the "MODIT.ui" stuff was coming from and so they could see a demo of what I was trying to solve

Comment: @Barmar - Yeah, that was bad wording on my part. What I meant was that in the big application I'm working on I am using an event handler to trigger the CSS change - this was simply a small demo to show my issue. The handler triggers correctly, but the CSS doesn't animate and my question was how I could fix that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wait so let me get this straight...

You have a black box and want it to move upwards when the page loads?

In that case, set the black box to static CSS (not written in the JavaScript function), for the original state of the black box (the original location, etc).

Then, when the main function is called, set the box to the new style.

Comment: Hmm, that sounds like a good idea, but at Mod.it it is preferable that all code, even the CSS, is made dynamically. I did think of that solution, but was wondering if there is anything else that could potentially be done apart from timeouts and static css?